# AFAbstractRESTClient throwing "unrecognized selector sent to class" exception

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, afabstractrestclient

I have two projects in XCode where I'm using AFAbstractRESTClient to make REST calls to a remote endpoint.  One is a simple project I created to test using AFAbstractRESTClient and it works just fine.

The second project is where I really want to integrate AFAbstractRESTClient but I'm getting a `+[NSURL URLWithPath:andParams:]: unrecognized selector sent to class` exception in AbstractGETAPICall.m on line 19:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithPath:[self path] andParams:params]];
```

`URLWithPath:andParams:` is defined in NSURL+QueryParams.h

I installed AFAbstractRESTClient with CocoaPods and I opened the .xcworkspace file afterwords.  Is there some linking problem where its not able to see that `URLWithPath:andParams:` exists?

EDIT: 
When I Option-Click URLWithPath:andParams: it says it is declared in NSURL+QueryParams.h so somehow Xcode appears to be forgetting that it knows that somewhere when its running.

Comment: I know there have historically been some linking issues with Categories in static libraries. It's been awhile, and I've never used CocoaPods or AFNetworking, but I would check for the -objC flag in the second project's 'Other Linker Flags' build setting.

Comment: You may also need the -all_load linker flag.

Comment: Unfortunately neither worked.  Thanks for the suggestions though!

Comment: Most likely the problem is that you have not included NSURL+QueryParams.m in your build.

Comment: @HotLicks NSURL+QueryParams.m is included in AbstractGETAPICall.m which is included in my class.  Shouldn't my including AbstractGETAPICall.h automatically cause NSURL+QueryParams.m to be included?

Comment: Including the .h doesn't automatically cause the .m to be built.  It must be included in the list of buildable parts.

Comment: In the left-hand "navigator" column click on NSURL+QueryParams.m (*not .h!*) and RMB -> Show File Inspector.  In the right-hand File Inspector column look at the "Target Membership" section and make sure that the box for your project executable is checked.

Comment: @HotLicks Only "Pods-AFAbstractRESTClient" is checked.  There is no entry for my project in the list.  However, when I look at my other sample project (where I'm not having this problem) it looks exactly the same.

Comment: You can fix this issue with this code: `#define MAKE_CATEGORIES_LOADABLE(UNIQUE_NAME) @interface FORCELOAD_##UNIQUE_NAME : NSObject @end @implementation FORCELOAD_##UNIQUE_NAME @end` and then put it into .m file like this: MAKE_CATEGORIES_LOADABLE(CategoryClassName). Code taken from here: https://github.com/kstenerud/Objective-Gems/blob/master/Objective-Gems/LoadableCategory.h

Comment: This may be a silly questions because you mentioned the xcworkspace but have you run pod install? This should add the dependencies needed, but check that your target's build phases/target dependencies lists the library your attempting to use.

Comment: Yep, ran pod install.